# How to fetch lightning record page metadata in apex?

Tags: apex

I am unable to fetch lightning record page metadata or flexipage in apex by using Metadata.Operations class. Dose someone know to how we can get metadata of lightning record page in apex

Answer (score 3):

FlexiPage Metadata Class contains data for all the Lightning Record Pages.

1. You should use the MetadataService and MetadataServiceExamples, can find it here:
   https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi
2. You should do it using Metadata.ReadFlexiPageResult.

   ```
           List<String> fullNames = LIST OF THE NAME YOU WANT TO RETRIEVE;
           String metadataType = 'FlexiPage';
           MetadataService.IReadResult readResult = new 
           MetadataService.ReadFlexiPageResult();
           readResult = service.readMetadata(metadataType,fullNames);
           List<MetadataService.Metadata> listForLoop = readResult.getRecords();
           Boolean flagForChange = false;
           for(MetadataService.Metadata temp : listForLoop){
               MetadataService.FlexiPage obj = (MetadataService.FlexiPage) temp;
               system.debug(obj.fullName);
           }
   ```
3. The following is the FlexiPage Metadata API:

   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm

Comment: Please let me know if it helps you and if yes mark as the solution.

Comment: Where does the `service` parameter come from?